# Creating key value pair while reading file shell bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, unix

I have a file in custom_target.config. I have a shell script that is going to read through this config file. The config file is split up by the name of the file and the target directory I am trying to move it to. I was wondering what the best way is to split line in the file and start moving the files to the respective locations.

```
EXAMPLE_FILE /home/user/example
EXAMPLE_FILE_1 /home/user/example
EXAMPLE_FILE_1 /home/user/example/subfolder
```

Attemp so far:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    for element in $line
    do
      echo $element
    done
    #echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Feels like this should be over on the *nix SO. I have just been looking at the same thing :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Do you want to move `EXAMPLE_FILE` to `/home/user/example`? Try `while IFS= read -r file dir; do echo mv "${file}" "${dir}"; done < "$1" and remove `echo` when it is what you want.

Comment: Be nice to your scripts: ensure that you feed them valid POSIX text files (that end with a newline) instead of cluttering them with hacks like `|| [[ -n $line ]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `read` do the word splitting instead of trusting `$line` not to do anything odd.

```
while read -r key value; do
  echo "KEY: $key"
  echo "VALUE: $value"
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can use Awk:

### copy files

```
  `awk '{printf "cp "$1" "$2}' custom_target.config`
```

### move files

```
  `awk '{printf "mv "$1" "$2}' custom_target.config`
```

print a strings to be executed: (`cp file_name path`)

`$1` - first field separated by space (file name)

`$2` - second field separated by space (path name)

`awk '{printf "cp "$1" "$2}' custom_target.config`

use **``** for execute the output strings